# "ClickTag is required, but not found." Adwords not accepting swf banner

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-ads-api, clicktag

I have created a swf banner for Google Adwords. But on uploading the Ad I got this error

"ClickTag is required, but not found."

Also on flash preview I can click and go to the destination url but after publishing I can not click.

I performed the following steps

- On the top of images layers, I added another layer
- drew a rectangle on the new layer
- converted it into movie clip and named it click
- made its alpha zero
- Right click on the layer and opened the action panel
- Added following code

  `function getTarget(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
  var urlTarget:URLRequest=new
  URLRequest("http://www.mywebsite.com");
  try {
  navigateToURL(urlTarget,'_blank');
  } catch (event:Error) {
  trace("Cannot perform link action");
  }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

a clicktag is not simply a hardcoded link in your source code, it is a property that can be set from the outside without modifying the code

ie:

```
if (root.loaderInfo.parameters.ClickTag && root.loaderInfo.parameters.ClickTag.substr(0,4) == "http") 
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.ClickTag), "_blank");
}
```

the ClickTag variable can be modified from the markup code without needing a flash developer

```
<object type=”application/x-shockwave-flash” 
        data=”http://www.examplewebsite.com/banner.swf?
        ClickTag=http://www.destinationURL.com” width=”300″ height=”250″>
```